# JDBC reader not reading properly when pageSize is less than commit interval

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working on JDBCPagingItemReading and testing it for differenet scenarios for 20 records

[image]

In the first scenario when the pageSize is more than commit interval it is working fine as expected.But when the pageSize is less than commit Interval job is finished with reading all the records from database.Is this the actual behaviour or i am doing some thing wrong

Comment: This is expected behaviour: Pagesize is used to limit the number of rows read per batch call.

Comment: I also think it is the expected behaviour. Page size relates to how to get incoming data and commit interval is related to how to "write" it (in batch terms).